# If $g\circ f$ is a bijection then $f$ and $g$ are bijection too.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

**Statement**

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y\rightarrow Z$ function. If $(g\circ f)$ is a bijection then $f$ and $g$ are bijection too.

So if $(g\circ f)$ is a bijection then it is a injection and surjection too.

So if $(f\circ g)$ is a injection then there exist a function $h:Z\rightarrow X$ such that $(h\circ g)\circ f=h\circ (g\circ f)=\text{Id}_X$ so that $f$ is an injection.

Then if $(f\circ g)$ is a surjection then by $\text{AC}$ there exist a function $k:Z\rightarrow X$ such that $g\circ (f\circ k)=(g\circ f)\circ k=\text{Id}_Z$ so that $g$ is a surjection.

Now unfortunately I don't be able to understand if $f$ is a surjection and if $g$ is an injection. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: The statement is false. Take $f\colon\{1\}\to\{1,2\}$ that sends $1$ to $1$; take $g\colon\{1,2\}\to \{1\}$. Then $g\circ f$ is the identity on $\{1\}$, but $f$ is not surjective and $g$ is not injective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f,g:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n\ge 1$ $f(n)=n+1$ and for every $n\ge 1$ $g(n)=n-1$ if $n>1$ and $g(1)=1$ then $f\circ g=\mathrm{identity}$ ($f$ acts first) but $f,g$ and $g\circ f$ are not bijections.

Comment: @JCCA Excuse me but $0\in\Bbb N$ so that I don't understand your counterexample: so could you edit it?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro It's a matter of convention whether $0\in\mathbb{N}$; this answer takes the stance that $0\not\in\mathbb{N}$. If you want you can just "shift down by one."

Comment: @NoahSchweber Okay, but if $0\notin\Bbb N$ then it seems to me that $(f\circ g)[\Bbb N]=\{n\in\Bbb N:n\ge 2\}\neq\Bbb N$. So what can you say about?

Comment: Indeed as you can check $(f\circ g)(1)=f(g(1))=f(1)=1+1=2\neq 1$ so that $(f\circ g)\neq\text{identity}$ as JCCA states!

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro Note the parenthetical "($f$ acts first)" in the answer. JCAA is using the convention - which personally I hate, but they are explicitly stating it - that composition is written left-to-right. In more common notation they're talking about $g\circ f$.